# Propositional Logic Exercise

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I need your help in solving an exercise in propositional logic:

I am trying to prove that this :

```
(Y ∧ ¬Z) ∨ ((X ∨ Y) ∧ (¬Y ∨ X))
```

is equivalent to this (according to the solution of the exercise)

```
(X ∨ ¬Z) ∧ (X ∨ Y)
```

What I did so far:

```
(Y ∧ ¬Z) ∨ ((X ∨ Y) ∧ (¬Y ∨ X)) ≡ (Y ∧ ¬Z) ∨ (( X ∧ (¬Y ∨ X)) ∨ ( Y ∧ (¬Y ∨ X))
 ≡ (Y ∧ ¬Z) ∨ (( X ∧ ¬Y) ∨ (X ∧ X) ∨ (Y ∧ ¬Y) ∨ (Y ∧ X))
 ≡ (Y ∧ ¬Z) ∨ ( X ∧ ¬Y) ∨ X ∨ (Y ∧ X)
 ≡ (Y ∧ ¬Z) ∨ X ∨ ( X ∧ ¬Y) ∨ (Y ∧ X)
 ≡ ((X ∨ Y) ∧ (X ∨ ¬Z)) ∨ ( X ∧ ¬Y) ∨ (Y ∧ X)
```

Now this part what I am having issues with, I could apply the distributive law again, but I don't see how this part will turn False at some point. :

```
( X ∧ ¬Y) ∨ (Y ∧ X) ≡ ( X ∨ (Y ∧ X)) ∧ ( ¬Y ∨ (Y ∧ X))
                    ≡ (X ∨ Y) ∧ (X ∨ X) ∧ (¬Y ∨ Y) ∧ (¬Y ∨ X)
                    ≡ (X ∨ Y) ∧ X ∧ Y ∧ (¬Y ∨ X)
```

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to apply [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic) to $(X ∨ Y) ∧ (¬Y ∨ X)$ to get : $X ∨ (Y ∧ ¬Y)$.

And $(Y ∧ ¬Y) \equiv \text F$ and $X ∨ \text F \equiv X$.

Thus, starting from the original formula :

> $$[(Y ∧ ¬Z) ∨ ((X ∨ Y) ∧ (¬Y ∨ X))] \equiv [(Y ∧ ¬Z) ∨ (X ∨ (Y ∧ ¬Y))] \equiv$$
>
> $$[(Y ∧ ¬Z) ∨ (X ∨ \text F)] \equiv [(Y ∧ ¬Z) ∨ X].$$

Comment: I did apply the distributive law: (( X ∧ ¬Y) ∨ (X ∧ X) ∨ (Y ∧ ¬Y) ∨ (Y ∧ X)) ≡ X ∨ (Y ∧ X), because (Y ∧ ¬Y)  is false and also ( X ∧ ¬Y),  but I still got (Y ∧ X). I would appreciate another hint.

Comment: @highads - $( X ∧ ¬Y)$ is not False. See the answer above.

Comment: I just don't fully understand  how you distribute to reduce the formula to ∨(∧¬). Because I assumed you distribute X over ( ¬∨) and also Y over (¬∨).

Comment: @highads - sorry, I cannot understand what you do not understand :-) Distributivity : $X∨(Y∧¬Y) \equiv [(X∨Y)∧(X ∨¬Y) ]$.

Comment: oh I am sorry, now I get it. I thought in a very complicated way.